# Listen to specific Bluetooth characteristic value in backgeound

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I know using `iBeacon` I can listen to some `UUID` when the app is closed.
I would like to listen to specific value of **characteristic** when the app is closed.

So , when the app is **open** and connected to device, I get this delegate when a new data arrive  :

```
  func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

           if characteristic.uuid.uuidString == characteristicUUID {

             if let str = NSString(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
```

Is there a way to get this delegate when the app is closed ? so I can then check and see I get the right string I am waiting for ?

I know I can listen to this usually only when I am connected to the device, but I want to listen even when not connected .

Is **iBeacon** the only way to interact with any **BLE** when the app is closed ?
Its pretty limited.

Comment: You can enable background bluetooth central mode for your app and you will continue to receive calls to the delegate method when the peripheral indicates a change, but you need to maintain the connection to the peripheral.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks I'v enabled them- but I asked about the case when the app is closed, in this case you can't keep the communication open ...

Comment: It depends what you mean by "closed"; the normal state is suspended in the background and this works as I described.  If the app has been terminated by the system (say due to memory pressure) then you can opt-in to Bluetooth state restoration (see the Core Bluetooth programming guide) and your app will be relaunched into the background when the peripheral is seen or indicates a change.  If your app has been terminated by the user swiping up then your app cannot do anything until it is relaunched by the user.

Comment: @Paulw11 So I talked about the case when the user closed the app of course . Usually you close apps, thats the nature of it, and then, you want to get an update about some value/sensor, and this is impossible right now (according to you). The only way to wake a closed app(by user) is iBeacon- which is pretty limited . So to make sure, with all the talkings about IoT, today iOS can't wait for specific string data when the app is just closed...

Comment: You didn't clarify what you meant by "the user closed the app" because the user can close the app in two ways: by tapping the home button and by double-tapping the home button and swiping the app upwards. The first allows the app to enter into a background state, the second does not.

Comment: I am talking about the second. I think 80% of all iOS users, have the habit to double tap and close apps, at least once a day. In this case, which is most cases, you can't for example keep listening to your family's heart sensor and know if something happens. Sounds pretty lame :)

Comment: I don't know about 80% of users.  I never swipe up on an app unless it is misbehaving and this is Apple's recommendation.  But in general in iOS if a user swipes up then iOS assumes the user wanted it dead and it won't be relaunched until the user taps the icon to do so. Even iBeacon won't relaunch a terminated app

Comment: @Paulw11 seems that Apple approach, as you said, is to stay connected all the time and use restore mode for other cases. I summed it up in my answer to have this in mind. I find it strange that you can't listen to the string" paul" all the time if the user allows you to do so. Anyway, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering my question to also have this information.(thanks also to Paul )

So today in order to be able to get information from a hardware when the app is completely closed (by the user or system), you can only use `iBeacons` .

But iBeacons are pretty limited, you can only listen to some `UUID/MJ/MN` and thats it.

**What if you want to get sensor data all the time ?**

The approach `Apple` takes, is that you should stay connected to your device all the time. So when your app is in background ,you simply get the same `delegates` when `characteristic` is being updated its value and you are still connected.

**What if you go out ?**

Connection is lost, you ask to search again for devices, when you back home you have a connection and you can again listen automatically.

**What if the *system* cancel your app to free up memory ?**

In this case you use the `Preservation and Restoration`, which will restore your `CBCentral` when the app **detects again the hardware** . To do so :

```
centralManager=CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: ["key":CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey])
```

You set here a `CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey` with your "key".
When iOS detects the signal again, you get this delegate :

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, willRestoreState dict: [String : Any]) {
    print(dict)
}
```

with a list of your objects and you can again get the connection and data .

**bottom line :**
The approach is -if you need sensor data constantly , for example to open and close a lock, you stay connected all the time.(and not use iBeacon)

**another bottom line :**
If user closes your app, as said here by Paul, you can't really continue and listen, which is in my opinion a pretty strange approach .

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html